# Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: java, sql, xml

I am working on test environment.

Here is the query which I used in java

```
String sql =     "INSERT INTO PO_PART_XML_IF (INTERFACE_ID, INTERFACE_TRANSACTION_ID,"
                + " O_SEQ_NO, PART_NO,  O_QTY, O_TYPE_CODE, R_R_NO"
                + " ,O_LINE_COMMENT, C_CODE, INPUT_USER_ID, INPUT_TIMESTAMP, "
                + "LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID, LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP ) VALUES (   

                 G_REPAIR_PARTS_IF_SEQ.nextval,"+transactionnumber+",'"+orderSecNo+"','"+  
                 job.getPartNo()+"',"+ Long.parseLong(job.getOrderQty())+",'"+job.getDeliveryType().getTitle()+"','"+job.getServiceReceiptNo()+"','"+replaceSingleQuote(job.getOrderComment())+"','"+currencyCode+"','"+inputUserID+"',SYSDATE,'"+inputUserID+"',SYSDATE)";
```

When I did some test then I got this error in log files :

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

I checked directly on pl/sql, It is working fine.I mean insert data. but when you test with java program, it show me this error.

Any Idea!

Comment: First thing to fix: stop building up SQL by including values like this. Use parameterized SQL. That may or may not fix the problem, but it's definitely the first thing you should fix, IMO.

Comment: Why would you parse a `long` value just to turn it into a String.  Isn't it a String already?

Comment: you are trying do insert query, error suggest some data access issues, i will say you are not giving us exact amount information to solve your problems

Comment: Either you are not using the correct API for insert query, or there is some problem with these "parameters", so print the SQL with parameters in place and try to execute directly on DB, that will at least tell you if the query is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query is ok (you'll have to check that), the code which should work is

```
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

You are probably using

```
statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

which is wrong for insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code that actually executes the query, but judging by the message it seems you are executing as if it returns data, ie a SELECT, but it's an UPDATE statement.

Try executing it using the appropriate API for an update.